# Winning strategy for solitaire?

Tags: game-theory, card-games

I'm talking about the [Klondike solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_(solitaire)), turning three cards at once to the waste and placing no limit on passes through the deck.

I know there isn't always a winning strategy, a counterexample can be easily constructed, but I was wondering what are the minimal conditions in order to guarantee the existence of a winning strategy.

I'm also interested in seeing the tools required to tackle the problem.

Edit: For those who aren't familiar with the game, you can play it [here](http://www.solitr.com/).

Comment: Are you talking about [Klondike solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_solitaire)?  Your question is very vague.

Comment: @MJD Yes, one of its variations. Let me add it to the post.